# React search bar to render cards dynamically

Tags: reactjs, state, react-props, searchbar

I have a movie app which displays a card for each movie in a state.

I would like to use a dynamic search bar to render movies corresponding to the search input value.

For instance, if I start to write "Har", I want to see only movies with a title that begins with "Har".

The app code :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Logo from "../components/Logo";
import Search from "../components/Search";
import Add_movie_button from "../components/Add_movie_button";
import Random_movie_button from "../components/Random_movie_button";
import Movie_card from "../components/Movie_card";
import axios from "axios";

const BASE_URL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/";
const API_KEY = "4bcd155b9b8734cb8559319cdbfaf62f";

function App() {
  const [movieinfos, setMovieinfos] = useState([]);
  console.log(movieinfos);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000")
      .then(function (response) {
        const movies = response.data.movies;
        console.log(response.data.movies);
        return Promise.all(
          movies.map((movie) =>
            axios.get(
              `${BASE_URL}${movie.movieid}?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=fr`
            )
          )
        );
      })
      .then((responses) => {
        console.log(responses);
        setMovieinfos(
          responses.map((response) => ({
            Genres: response.data.genres,
            Overview: response.data.overview,
            Poster: response.data.poster_path,
            Company: response.data.production_companies,
            Release: response.data.release_date,
            Title: response.data.title,
            Id: response.data.id,
          }))
        );
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="Header">
        <Logo />
      </div>
      <div className="Menu">
        <Search movieinfos={movieinfos} setMovieinfos={setMovieinfos} />
        <Add_movie_button />
        <Random_movie_button data={movieinfos} />
      </div>
      <div className="Movies">
        {movieinfos.map((movie) => (
          <Movie_card key={movie.Title} data={movie} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The search bar code :

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";

const Search = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <div className="Search">
      <input
        type="search"
        id="Search_input"
        placeholder="Rechercher un film ..."
        value= //WHAT DO I NEED TO WRITE HERE ?
        onChange={(event) =>
          /*WHAT DO I NEED TO WRITE HERE ?*/ event.target.value
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Search;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a state variable

```
[searchWord, setSearchWord] = useState('')
```

your input would then contain

```
value={searchWord}
onChange={e => setSearchWord(e.target.value)}
```

You could then filter your array movieinfos with the searchWord and map the returning array to display only the movies with the search world

```
movieinfos.filter(movie => movie.title.includes(searchWord)).map(movie => return <Movie_card key={movie.Title} data={movie} />)
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand where i need to put the filter code.

Don't I need to keep the first .map fucntion that displays cards ?

Comment: Right, sorry I thought you were displaying the movies in the search component. The filter code would go in your App component and so would the useState, you would have to pass the values to the search box component. Then, in you App, if the search is not null, filter before mapping